# Move towards the center as the view rotates around the center of the view

Tags: android, animation

I have the following circle that I would like to rotate around the center of the screen, which I am doing it. But I would also like to make it closer and closer to the center as it rotates. Anybody has any suggestion and code sample on how I can achieve that?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ring1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ring">
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@color/main_blue"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="Start"
    android:onClick="startAnimation" />
```

Code for the ring:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <size android:width="25dp" android:height="25dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/main_red" />
</shape>
```

Code for Animation:

```
public void startAnimation(View view) {
    LinearLayout ring1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ring1);
    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(false);
    RotateAnimation rAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, 328f, 100f);
    rAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    rAnimation.setDuration(5000);      
    animationSet.addAnimation(rAnimation);
    ring1.startAnimation(animationSet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another `TranslateAnimation(int fromXDelta, int toXDelta, int fromYDelta, int toYDelta)` animation to the `AnimationSet`. You can calculate the x and y deltas by measuring the size of the screen, dividing that by two, and subtracting half the size of the view you want to put at the center.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int centerOfScreenX = size.x / 2;
int xDelta = width - ring1.getWidth()/2

TranslateAnimation transAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, xDelta, 0, 0);
transAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
transAnimation.setDuration(5000);
animationSet.addAnimation(rAnimation);
```

============== EDIT ================

The animation is more complex than I first realized, so a different method may be necessary: since it's easy to rotate a view around its center, we could rotate a `LinearLayout` that matches the parent in width, and which contains an `ImageView` aligned to its left. Then the left `padding` of the `LinearLayout` can be animated simultaneously. This should result in a "spiraling" animation, with the image rotating around the center of the screen, while approaching it.

Here's the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ring1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ring"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Start"
    android:onClick="startAnimation" />
```

And here's the method:

```
public void startAnimation(View view) {
    final LinearLayout ring1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ring1);

    final int origWidth = ring1.getWidth();
    int halfWidth = origWidth / 2;
    int halfHeight = ring1.getHeight() / 2;
    final int targetPadding = halfWidth - halfHeight;

    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = new ObjectAnimator().ofFloat(0, 1);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int paddingLeft = (int) (targetPadding * (float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
            ring1.setPadding(paddingLeft, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.setDuration(5000);
    valueAnimator.start();

    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(false);
    RotateAnimation rAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, halfWidth, halfHeight);
    rAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    rAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    ring1.startAnimation(rAnimation);
}
```

I slightly changed the timings to make it more obvious what's going on. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I had tried this before. If you code this you'll see that it doesn't give the effect I'm looking for. I want the center of rotation be always the center of screen and the circle as it rotates around this fixed center to reduce the radius of rotation, something like a spiral movement. I think what you suggested changes the center of rotation. Because if you really think about it, it's not a constant translation to right, depending on where the circle is the translation could be at any direction (always towards the center of the rotation).

Comment: Hey, you are right, the original solution wouldn't work. I tried a different approach and I've updated the answer accordingly. Let me know if this is any better.